# Problem between spring and angular with localhost:7070/login

Tags: angular, spring, spring-security, postman

I am currently starting a project in JAVA Spring for the back and in Angular for the front. On the back I did my first "User" class on the spring side to the controller and on the Angular side I went all the way to fetch the list.

class User :

```
package com.tracker.EsportTracker.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinTable;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import com.tracker.EsportTracker.models.Username;



@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idUser;
    private String lastNameUser;
    private String firstNameUser;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private Username username;
    private String password;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date dateNaissanceUser;
    private String emailUser;
    private long phoneNumberUser;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "PROFILS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_user", referencedColumnName = "idUser"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_role", referencedColumnName = "idRole"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
    
    public User() { 
        
    }
    
    public User(String lastNameUser, String firstNameUser, Username username, String password, 
            Date dateNaissanceUser, String emailUser, long phoneNumberUser) {
        this.lastNameUser = lastNameUser;
        this.firstNameUser = firstNameUser;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.dateNaissanceUser = dateNaissanceUser;
        this.emailUser = emailUser;
        this.phoneNumberUser = phoneNumberUser;
    }
    
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public Long getIdUser() {
        return idUser;
    }
    public void setIdUser(Long idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }
    public String getlastNameUser() {
        return lastNameUser;
    }
    public void setlastNameUser(String lastNameUser) {
        this.lastNameUser = lastNameUser;
    }
    public String getfirstNameUser() {
        return firstNameUser;
    }
    public void setfirstNameUser(String firstNameUser) {
        this.firstNameUser = firstNameUser;
    }
    public Username getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(Username username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public Date getDateNaissanceUser() {
        return dateNaissanceUser;
    }
    public void setDateNaissanceUser(Date dateNaissanceUser) {
        this.dateNaissanceUser = dateNaissanceUser;
    }
    public String getEmailUser() {
        return emailUser;
    }
    public void setEmailUser(String emailUser) {
        this.emailUser = emailUser;
    }
    public long getphoneNumberUser() {
        return phoneNumberUser;
    }
    public void setphoneNumberUser(long phoneNumberUser) {
        this.phoneNumberUser = phoneNumberUser;
    }

}
```

Usercontroller :

```
package com.tracker.EsportTracker.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.tracker.EsportTracker.entities.User;
import com.tracker.EsportTracker.service.interfaces.IUserService;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    IUserService userService;
    
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return userService.findAll();
    }
}
```

Then Angular,
UserService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  private baseUrl = "http://localhost:7070/users";
  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }

  public findAll() : Observable<any>{
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(`${this.baseUrl}`);
  }
}
```

My problem is that apparently my inspection (with f12) tells me that I am not returning JSON data but an HTML.

```
 ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', url: 'http://localhost:7070/login', ok: false, …}
error
: 
error
: 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:20558:41) at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8237:171) at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:32181:49 at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:32181:30) at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8237:54) at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:32492:25) at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8237:54) at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8038:37) at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8314:26)
text
: 
"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n  <head>\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no\">\n    <meta name=\"description\" content=\"\">\n    <meta name=\"author\" content=\"\">\n    <title>Please sign in</title>\n    <link href=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" integrity=\"sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\">\n    <link href=\"https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/signin/signin.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\"/>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n     <div class=\"container\">\n      <form class=\"form-signin\" method=\"post\" action=\"/login\">\n        <h2 class=\"form-signin-heading\">Please sign in</h2>\n        <p>\n          <label for=\"username\" class=\"sr-only\">Username</label>\n          <input type=\"text\" id=\"username\" name=\"username\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Username\" required autofocus>\n        </p>\n        <p>\n          <label for=\"password\" class=\"sr-only\">Password</label>\n          <input type=\"password\" id=\"password\" name=\"password\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Password\" required>\n        </p>\n<input name=\"_csrf\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"uTMoq8Gu_qEn-PqtnNNcDjGd8kBolY5S1FvdftWnaM9n4C8hilBOnvmZnZUKzc2VpP5oPgGp33kMpLt_tzrpR7HCXv4D0EpF\" />\n        <button class=\"btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block\" type=\"submit\">Sign in</button>\n      </form>\n</div>\n</body></html>"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
headers
: 
HttpHeaders
lazyInit
: 
() => {…}
lazyUpdate
: 
null
normalizedNames
: 
Map(0) {size: 0}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
message
: 
"Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:7070/login"
name
: 
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok
: 
false
status
: 
200
statusText
: 
"OK"
url
: 
"http://localhost:7070/login"
[[Prototype]]
: 
HttpResponseBase
constructor
: 
class HttpErrorResponse
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

I was redirected to a login page
I first thought it was my server not wanting to let Angular access the data, so I created a sucurityConfig.java

```
package com.tracker.EsportTracker.config;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

import com.tracker.EsportTracker.service.impl.AppUserDetailsService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private AppUserDetailsService appUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder baBCryptPasswordEncoder;

    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(appUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(baBCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().and().formLogin().permitAll().and().logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll().and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
    }
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean simpleCorsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();

        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*")); // GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));

        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }

}
```

But it still doesn't work and POSTMAN doesn't return any value to me.
Can you help me please

Answer (score 0):

Your security configuration is wrong and not getting picked up by spring security, and since its not getting picked up, what you are getting back is the login page that spring security is providing by default.

Spring security is *secure by default* meaning that as soon as you have spring security on your class path (as a dependency in your project) it will per default lock everything down.

Then it is your job to configure spring security if you dont want the default settings.

I have no idea where you got your configuration from, but it is faulty. There is nothing as a `configure` function in Spring Security 6, and no one is calling that function.

```
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(appUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(baBCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().and().formLogin().permitAll().and().logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll().and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
    }
```

I have no idea where you got this code from.

This example below is taken from the spring security documentations sample github repository of a basic hello world security program using form login.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new AppUserDetailsService();
    }
}
```

It does not have to be more complicated than this, and i strongly suggest that you read the [spring security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/getting-started.html), and look at the [samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/hello-security-explicit/src/main/java/example/SecurityConfiguration.java)

Comment: Hello, I received this code from my JAVA/JEE trainer. I just apply what he told me but I will try your code! THANK YOU

Comment: I can't do it at all, I'm still stuck in the login.. I think there is a problem in my understanding. Can you give me directions please?

Comment: stack overflow is not a forum, its a QA site, if you wish more lengthy help i suggest join a discord server. Or you update your question with the current code, the request you are doing and proper debugging logs.

Answer (score -1):

In your *UserController*, instead of a **List**

```java
@GetMapping("/users")
public List<User> findAll() {
   return userService.findAll();
}
```

You should return a **ResponseEntity**. In your case:

```java
@GetMapping("/users")
public ResponseEntity<User> findAll() {
   return new ResponseEntity<User>(userService.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I hope this will be helpful.